# Chrome console POST jquery 404 (Not Found) : jquery.min.js:2

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, post

Level: Newbie (JavaScript, jQuery, CodeIgniter)

I make a function for change password, then I run it in localhost with chrome browser. I've got trouble when I want to call PHP function from my JavaScript. Chrome console said that the page is Not Found and the link for the document is jquery.min.js:2

I don't know what I should do because I'm new with jQuery.
Here's my html in pengaturan.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />

<script src="jq/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jq/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jq/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="date/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="date/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="date/js/console.js"></script>

<script src="jq/proses/set_ip.js"></script>
<script src="jq/proses/newpass/newpass.js"></script>

<script src="jq/proses/script.js"></script>

<title>edc - e diabet consult</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Pengaturan</h1>

<p align="left" class="navigation">

<a href="settings.html" class="back">
<img src="ico/kembali.png">
</a>

</p>

<form id="form_pengaturan" action="post">

<p align="center">

<strong>Password lama:</strong><br />
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/><br />

<strong>Password baru:</strong><br />
<input type="password" name="newpass" id="newpass"/><br />

<strong>Konfirmasi password baru:</strong><br />
<input type="password" name="confnewpass" id="confnewpass"/><br /><br/>

<input type="button" value="Simpan" onclick="cek()" id="simpan" class="button"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button"/>

</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my javascript in newpass.js

```
/*Don't forget to add set_ip.js and jquery before you use this script in HTML page to make it work*/
var urlini = seturl();
var part= 'newpass/';

$(document).ready(function() {
currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
$("#tgllahir_inp").kendoDatePicker({
                // defines the start view
                start: "year",
        min: new Date(currentYear-50,'0','01'),
        max: new Date(currentYear-14,'0','01'),
                    // defines when the calendar should return date
                    depth: "day",

                    // display month and year in the input
                    format: "yyyy-MM-dd"
                });
});

function cek() {
    pass =  /^([-a-z0-9_-])+$/i.test($("#pass").val());     
    newpass =  /^([-a-z0-9_-])+$/i.test($("#newpass").val());
    confnewpass =  /^([-a-z0-9_-])+$/i.test($("#confnewpass").val());

    var form_reg =  $("input").val();
    if(form_reg == "")
    {
        alert("Semua data harus diisi.");       
    }
    else if($("#newpass, #confnewpass").val().length  == 0 || $("#newpass, #confnewpass").val().length  < 5 || $("#newpass, #confnewpass").val().length > 15)
    {
        alert("Terdapat kesalahan atau data kosong pada pengisian data.\nPastikan password Anda lebih dari 5 dan kurang dari 15 karakter.");        
    }
    else if( !pass || !newpass || !confnewpass || $("#newpass").val() != $("#confnewpass").val())
    {
        alert("Terdapat kesalahan atau data kosong pada pengisian data.\nPastikan password Anda sesuai.");      
    }
    else
    {
        $.post(urlini+part+'cek',
            $('#form_pengaturan').serialize(),function(msg){
            if(msg == '1')
            {               
                alert("Data berhasil disimpan!");
                window.location="index.html";
            }
            else if(msg == '0')
            {
                alert("Password yang anda masukkan tidak benar!");
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Here's my php controller (server side) in newpass.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class newpass extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('newpass_model','npmod');
    }

    function cek()
{               
    $q = $this->npmod->pasien_pass();
    echo $q;
}
}
?>
```

Here's my php model (server side) in newpass_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class newpass_model extends CI_Model {

    public function pasien_pass(){

    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $pass = md5($this->input->post("pass"));

    $query = $this->db->where("iduser",$id)->get("user");

    if( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) {
        $row    = $query->row();
        $oldpass= $row->password;

        if($pass==$oldpass)
        {
            $newpass = md5($this->input->post("newpass"));
            $confnewpass = base64_encode($this->input->post("confnewpass"));

            $data = array(
                'password' => $newpass,
                'passbit_user' => $confnewpass            
            );
            $this->db->where('iduser',$id);
            $this->db->update('user',$data);    
            return"1";
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    } else {
        return "0";
    }    
    }
}
?>
```

When I run it, Chrome console said that the page is Not Found and the link for the document is jquery.min.js:2 Do you have an idea what should I do?

Comment: What url are you trying to post to? Does the network panel show the correct url?

Comment: @Eloff I have no idea what do you mean by "the network panel show the correct url"...

Comment: Ok, then I recommend you get familiar with the chrome dev tools. The network panel shows all requests and responses. Does your `$.post(urlini+part+'cek', ...` actually use the correct url? Check out https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: @Eloff I've got this as the respond:
Request URL:http://localhost/diabet_console/newpass/cek
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
From the other functions that had already working on this application, it's a correct url. That's what I thought.

Comment: If the url is correct and you get a 404, the error must be on the server side. I'm not familiar with codeigniter, so I'm only guessing here, but maybe the routing or controller is broken.

Comment: @Eloff the truth is, I was copied this file from another file and I forget to change the file name -___-" But, after I change the file name I still couldn't change the password. So, I think my php code is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The error 404 not found happened because I'd forgotten to change the file name of php files. The truth is I copied those php file from other file where the function is working.

Well, after that I change all my php code, all is alright.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try in this order:

```
<script src="jq/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jq/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="date/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="date/js/console.js"></script>

<script src="jq/proses/set_ip.js"></script>
<script src="jq/proses/newpass/newpass.js"></script>

<script src="jq/proses/script.js"></script>
```

You can remove these instances as you are using latest jQuery 1.9.1.

```
<script src="jq/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="date/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and mobile jQuery should come after jQuery library.

Instead you can try CDN hosted libraries.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when I tried, I've got different error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'sub' kendo.web.min.js:10
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'kendoDatePicker' newpass.js:7

Comment: i am sure you have a path issue. try debugging that in view source the libs are getting loaded or not.

Comment: how to do that? "debugging that in view source the libs are getting loaded or not" @Jai by the way, error that said not found still appear in chrome console POST http://localhost/diabet_console/newpass/cek 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5

Comment: if you are using chrome press `ctrl+u` and then click on the script links are those accessible or not.